# rosserial_arduino chipkit32 (arduino mega)

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ubuntu 12.04 Virtualbox fuerte from nootrix.com on my mac. I can use mpide and compile the normal example projects and communicate with the serial in the ubuntu environment, and I can run the ROS demo's, but as soon as I try to run the demo rosserial_arduino hello world, I continuously get:
"lost sync, restarting device..."
and when i look at the serial monitor, it is gibberish. Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46894/rosserial_arduino-chipkit32-(arduino-mega)/) by [wegunterjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3479/wegunterjr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2012-10-27**:
Did you successfully upload the ROS code to the Arduino first?  Also, I found that VMWare worked a little better than VirtualBox on my x86 machine.  VirtualBox seemed to loose sync more often, and sometimes took a couple tries to get connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the baudrate also correctly set on both sides? Perhaps try it first on a native ros installation (if available) and then move to virtualbox.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0